# mongodb update array element with $inc not working

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

This works fine when I hard code a value of 5 and update the array 3rd element:

```
BasicDBObject setDoc = new BasicDBObject();
setDoc.append("array.3.view_counter", 5);
```

But when I try and use `$inc` to update the view_counter instead of hard coding it in the following manner - I get a `com.mongodb.MongoException: not okForStorage Exception` from the java driver.

```
setDoc.append("array.3.view_counter", new BasicDBObject().append("$inc", new BasicDBObject().append("view_counter",1)))
```

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help or clues are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) needs to be at the top-level of your object, as in:

```
setDoc.append("$inc", new BasicDBObject("array.3.view_counter", 1));
```